# AngularJS Tabs with UI.Router

Tags: angularjs, tabs, router

I have a single page app with vertical tables to the left. I'm able to to click on each tab and the expected content is showing. The problem I'm having is I'm not able to programmatically change the **ng-checked** to "true" for the selected tab and "false" for the unselected tab. Because of this the selected tab is always on the first tab in the list of tabs. I've provided all the codes (6 files) to run this app so you can see what im talking about

**Index.html**

```
<html  ng-app= "mainApp">
<head>
<title>OneilAndK</title>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" >
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<link href="css/uxcore.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.4/angular.js"></script>
        <script src="http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-router/release/angular-ui-router.js"></script>
        <script src="routing.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="verticalTab.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
</head>

<body>


<div class="tabordion">


  <section id="section1">
    <input type="radio" name="sections" id="option1" ng-checked = true >
    <label ui-sref="About" for="option1">About</label>
    <article>

        <div  ui-view></div>
    </article>
  </section>


  <section id="section2">
    <input type="radio" name="sections" id="option2" ng-checked = false >
    <label ui-sref="Knowledge" for="option2"  >Knowledge</label>
    <article>
          <div  ui-view></div>
    </article>
  </section>


  <section id="section3">
    <input type="radio" name="sections" id="option3" ng-checked = false >
    <label ui-sref="Contact" for="option3"  >Contact</label>
    <article>
          <div  ui-view></div>
    </article>
  </section>
</div>


</body>
</html>
```

**About.html**

```
<p >This is my about page</p>
```

**Contact.html**

```
<p >This is my Contact page</p>
```

**Knowledge.html**

```
<p >This is my knowledge page</p>
```

**routing.js**

```
var app = angular.module('mainApp', ['ui.router']);

app.config(['$stateProvider','$urlRouterProvider', function($stateProvider,$urlRouterProvider){

  $urlRouterProvider.otherwise("Home.html")

  $stateProvider
    .state('Contact', {url:"/Contact",templateUrl:"Contact.html"})
    .state('Knowledge', {url:"/Knowledge",templateUrl:"Knowledge.html"})
    .state('About', {url:"/About",templateUrl:"About.html"})

  }]);
```

**verticalTab.css**

```
h1 {
  color: #333;
  font-family: arial, sans-serif;
  margin: 1em auto;
  width: 80%;
}

.tabordion {
  color: #333;
  display: block;
  font-family: arial, sans-serif;
  margin: auto;
  position: relative;
  width: 80%;
}

.tabordion input[name="sections"] {
  left: -9999px;
  position: absolute;
  top: -9999px;
}

.tabordion section {
  display: block;
}

.tabordion section label {
  background: #ccc;
  border:1px solid #fff;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: block;
  font-size: 1.2em;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding: 15px 20px;
  position: relative;
  width: 180px;
  z-index:100;
}

.tabordion section article {
  display: none;
  left: 230px;
  min-width: 300px;
  padding: 0 0 0 21px;
  position: absolute;  
  top: 0;
}

.tabordion section article:after {
  background-color: #ccc;
  bottom: 0;
  content: "";
  display: block;
  left:-229px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  width: 220px;
  z-index:1;
}

.tabordion input[name="sections"]:checked + label { 
  background: #eee;
  color: #bbb;
}

.tabordion input[name="sections"]:checked ~ article {
  display: block;
}


@media (max-width: 533px) {

  h1 {
    width: 100%;
  }

  .tabordion {
    width: 100%;
  }

  .tabordion section label {
    font-size: 1em;
    width: 160px;
  }  

 .tabordion section article {
    left: 200px;
    min-width: 270px;
  } 

  .tabordion section article:after {
    background-color: #ccc;
    bottom: 0;
    content: "";
    display: block;
    left:-199px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    width: 200px;

  }  

}


@media (max-width: 768px) {
  h1 {
    width: 96%;
  }

  .tabordion {
    width: 96%;
  }
}


@media (min-width: 1366px) {
  h1 {
    width: 70%;
  }

  .tabordion {
    width: 70%;
  }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure this is the complete code ? I don't understand how the views  change at the click of the radio button

Comment: Yes its all the code. Create all the 6 files in a local folder and run index.html

Answer (score 0):

I would use `angular-ui-bootstrap` to create tab panels. And for dynamically generating the tab headings you can use `stateHelper` module.

With `stateHelper` you can create a configuration object that you can also use inside a `ng-repeat` to generate the navbar of the tab panel.

The only tricky thing to make it work is the `$stateChangeStart` listener to calculate the index for the active route. Once the index is found it will be passed to `ui-bootstrap` via `$rootScope.active` variable.

Please have a look at the demo below or this [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/csLy4scw/3/).

```js
angular.module('demoApp', ['ui.router', 'ui.bootstrap', 'ui.router.stateHelper'])
    .run(['$state', '$rootScope', 'TABS_CONFIG', function($state, $rootScope, TABS_CONFIG) {
        // run needed to set the correct tab-index on load
        var tabs = TABS_CONFIG.children;
        $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', function(e, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams) {
            angular.forEach(tabs, function(item, index) {
                if (item.name == toState.name) {
                    $rootScope.active = index;
                }
            });
        });
    }])
    .constant('TABS_CONFIG', {
        name: 'tabs',
        templateUrl: 'tabs.html',
        abstract: true,
        children: [{
                url: '/about',
                name: 'about',
                template: '<div class="container"><h1>about</h1></div>'
                    //templateUrl: 'about.html'
            }, {
                url: '/contact',
                name: 'contact',
                template: '<div class="container"><h1>contact</h1></div>'
                    //templateUrl: 'contact.html'
            }, {
                url: '/knowhow',
                name: 'know-how',
                template: '<div class="container"><h1>knowhow</h1></div>'
                    //templateUrl: 'knowhow.html'
            },

        ]
    })
    .controller('mainController', function($scope, $state, TABS_CONFIG) {
        $scope.tabs = TABS_CONFIG.children;
        
        $scope.go = function(tab) {
            //$scope.active = $scope.tabs.indexOf(tab);
            $state.go(tab.name);
        };
    })
    .config(routes);

function routes($urlRouterProvider, stateHelperProvider, TABS_CONFIG) {
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/contact');

    stateHelperProvider.state(TABS_CONFIG, {
        keepOriginalNames: true
    });
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.5/angular.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-router/0.2.18/angular-ui-router.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-bootstrap/1.3.2/ui-bootstrap-tpls.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/marklagendijk/ui-router.stateHelper/master/statehelper.js"></script>
<div ng-app="demoApp" ng-controller="mainController">
    <div ui-view></div>

    <script type="text/ng-template" id="tabs.html">
        <uib-tabset active="active">
            <uib-tab index="$index" ng-repeat="tab in tabs" ng-click="go(tab)">
                <uib-tab-heading>{{tab.name}}</uib-tab-heading>
                <div ui-view></div>
            </uib-tab>
        </uib-tabset>
    </script>
</div>
```