# Angular tab content updating

Tags: angular, tabs, components

I need to create tabs for multiple courses Q&A using Angular. My code now look like that:

```
        <div class="row blue-text">
        <!-- User's questions list -->
        <div class="card">
            <div class="card-tabs">
            <ul class="tabs tabs-fixed-width">
                <li class="tab">
                    <a class="active blue-text" href="#python">python</a>
                </li>
                <li class="tab">
                    <a class = "blue-text" href="#java">java</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
            </div>
            <div class="card-content black-text">
                <div id="java">
                    <div>
                        <h3 class="center flow-text">Popular</h3>
                            <ul class="collection">
                            <li *ngFor="let question of questions" class="collection-item">
                                <p>
                                    <span class="qa-date">{{question.date_question}}</span>
                                </p>
                                <p>
                                    {{question.text_answer}}
                                    <span class="qa-date">{{question.date_answer}}</span>
                                </p>

                            </li>
                            <li class="divider"></li>
                            </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div id="python">

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Now I need the same tab for "python" course, but with other questions and answers. I don't want to duplicate code. Maybe I should create some component for question list? But I didn't find any working tutorial for tabs components. What is the best solution for this problem?

Comment: If you're looking for Angular 1.x you could do it like in my SO answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36971536/angularjs-tabs-with-ui-router/36972708#36972708) and for 2.x there is a blog post [here](https://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2015/04/09/developing-a-tabs-component-in-angular-2.html#demos) that's describing how to create it.

Comment: @AWolf This tutorial doesn't cover how to UPDATE tab content.